# I keep getting "modifier override is not applicable to local function' when trying to use onclicklistener

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to write a code for a small quiz app. When you click the plus button it takes you to a separate page where you input the question and answer. When you click the check button it takes you back to the previous page and a new button with the text set as the question is created. I'm running across an error when I try to put override under my buttonclick event. Is there anyway I can get around this?

Newbtn page:

```
    package com.example.test

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class Newbtn : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_newbtn)

        val newbutton = Button(this@Newbtn)
        val btn = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn2)
        val intent = getIntent()
        val test = intent.getStringExtra("test")

        newbutton.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        newbutton.width=1010
        newbutton.height=300
        newbutton.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        newbutton.translationX= 65F
        newbutton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"))
        newbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#250A43"))
        newbutton.text = test


        btn.setOnClickListener{
            val activityCode = 2
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent(this@Newbtn, QuestionPage::class.java), activityCode
            )

            override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
                if (requestCode == activityCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    val buttonText = data?.getStringExtra("test")
                    newbutton.text = buttonText
                }
        }
    }
}}
```

QuestionPage:

```
    package com.example.test

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class QuestionPage : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question_page)

        val btn3 = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn3)
        val intent = Intent(this@QuestionPage, Newbtn::class.java)
        val question = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.question)
        val answer = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer)
        val questiontext = question.text.toString()
        val answertext = answer.text.toString()
        val returnIntent = Intent()

        returnIntent.putExtra("test", questiontext)
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)
        finish()

        btn3.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `onActivityResult` is being interpreted as a local function within `onCreate` because you misplaced a `}` or two.

Comment: Where exactly should I position the } at?

Comment: You'll want to declare that `onActivityResult` either after whichever `}` closes the body of `onCreate`, or before the `onCreate` function.

Comment: When I try to do either I'm not able to use my activityCode and startActivityforResult code. I'm trying to position this somehow so that when the button gets clicked all of this happens so the data can get transferred. Kind of at a loss here

Answer (score 0):

Your `Newbtn` activity needs an `onCreate`function, and an `onActivityResult` one, both on the same level (inside the activity). Right now you have one nested inside the other, and inside an unclosed click listener lambda too.

Look at the vertical lines inside the IDE:

[image: a screenshot of the code with visible bracing guides]

See how whenever you open a scope, like with a function or lambda, there's a vertical line going from where you open that scope to where you close it, i.e. where the closing brace is? See how `btn.setOnClickListener` extends way further down than where it should end? How `onActivityResult` is inset inside it?

You can use these guides to help you clean things up when the bracing gets messed up, and make sure stuff is nested correctly. So `onActivityResult` should be on the same indented level as `onCreate`, which should be closed before `onActivityResult`'s opening brace - two separate lines, one after the other, each ending in a closing brace.

---

You can't reference `activityCode` because you're defining it inside the click listener lambda, it's a local variable in there, you can't see it from outside. It's not complaining in your current code because you have `onActivityResult` nested *inside* that lambda, where it can see the variable - but that code is broken because the function shouldn't be there anyway.

Just stick the `activityCode` value somewhere in your class, or even outside it (constants like this are a good candidate for `const val ACTIVITY_CODE = 2` declarations). Basically, your `onActivityResult` function needs to be able to handle any result that comes in, and refer to the possible identifying codes it's supposed to handle. Those shouldn't be defined secretly in the click listener, because then the activity gets the result back and says "what does **2** mean???"